# How can set the scrollbar position on orientation change?

Tags: android, scrollview, orientation

When I perform an orientation change the scrollview sometimes repositions so I lose the title (e.g. Chips Of Cholcolates...) textview of my view.

Here is what I want.

[image]

When I perform an orientation change I lose the title view.

[image]

This is my scrollview layout.

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview">
    <LinearLayout
        style = "@style/Activity"
        android:keepScreenOn="false"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/recipe_view" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            style="@style/name"
            android:hint="@string/recipe_title"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instructions"
            style="@style/instructions"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:hint="@string/recipe_instructions"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

In the fragment's onCreateView() I'm calling

```
  // correct the position of the scrollview
  mView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_view).scrollTo(0, 0);
```

to no effect.

The problem seems to be random.  Sometimes the scrollbar pushes the title out of view, sometimes it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can save and restore the scroll position when the orientation changes.

Save the current position in onSaveInstanceState:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
outState.putIntArray("ARTICLE_SCROLL_POSITION",
        new int[]{ mScrollView.getScrollX(), mScrollView.getScrollY()});}
```

And restore it in onRestoreInstanceState:

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
final int[] position = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("ARTICLE_SCROLL_POSITION");
if(position != null)
    mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mScrollView.scrollTo(position[0], position[1]);
        }
    });}
```

**--OR--**

A non-hacky way would be to just put `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` in that particular activity's tag in AndroidManifest.xml, and handle the activity recreation stuff yourself.

Comment: I am essentially already doing the first one though by setting scrollTo(0, 0) in my onCreateView method.  I don't need to save the state because I know the starting state that I want [(0, 0)].